# Time between two dates

Tags: php, mariadb-10.4

I want to calculate time in minutes between two dates **while** only including the time between `08:00:00` and `16:30:00`, also excluding Saturdays and Sundays. How can I achieve that? The following is my code which is just calculating time between two dates in general.

```
foreach($result as $row)
{
    $sub_array = array();
    $sub_array[] = floor((strtotime($row['app_2_date'])-strtotime($row['app_1_date']))/(60));
    $data[] = $sub_array;
}
```

I have tried the following code but still it's not working

```
foreach($result as $row)
{
    if
        (
            date('H:i:s', strtotime($row['app_2_date'])) > date('H:i:s', strtotime('1970-01-01 16:30:00'))||
            date('H:i:s', strtotime($row['app_2_date'])) < date('H:i:s', strtotime('1970-01-01 08:00:00'))
        )
    {
        $sub_array[] = floor((strtotime($row['app_3_date'])-strtotime($row['app_2_date']))/(60))-(15.5*60);
    }
    else
    {
        $sub_array[] = floor((strtotime($row['app_3_date'])-strtotime($row['app_2_date']))/(60));
    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly have you tried so far? The code misses all additional conditions you've specified. This looks like a good exercise to learn some test-driven development

Comment: Specify **precise** MySQL version.

Comment: MySQ version 7.4.10

Comment: your code is missing, you need to improve a little more.

Comment: *MySQ version 7.4.10* Such MySQL version not exists. Post precise output for `SELECT VERSION();` query.

Comment: 10.4.14-MariaDB

Answer (score 1):

```sql
WITH RECURSIVE
cte AS ( SELECT TIMESTAMP(DATE(MIN(dtfrom)), '08:00:00') dtfrom, 
                TIMESTAMP(DATE(MIN(dtfrom)), '16:30:00') dttill
         FROM src 
         UNION ALL
         SELECT dtfrom + INTERVAL 1 DAY,
                dttill + INTERVAL 1 DAY
         FROM cte
         WHERE dtfrom <= ( SELECT MAX(dttill)
                           FROM src ) )
SELECT src.id, SUM(TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, GREATEST(src.dtfrom, cte.dtfrom), LEAST(src.dttill, cte.dttill))) minutes
FROM src
CROSS JOIN cte
WHERE GREATEST(src.dtfrom, cte.dtfrom) < LEAST(src.dttill, cte.dttill)
  AND WEEKDAY(cte.dtfrom) < 5
GROUP BY src.id
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.4&fiddle=d215a63d291dc9eca1f8e3f7652c71f4)

Comment: There are **2** kind of minutes that need to be excluded from the date range; First all minutes of Saturdays and Sundays, then all minutes in specified range; Your query returns the latter (total minutes of specified excluded-range) for each row. **But** OP needs remaining minutes not those excluded; Once you fix that, this should be the accepted answer ;-)

Comment: @Top-Master *First all minutes of Saturdays and Sundays* `AND WEEKDAY(cte.dtfrom) < 5` excludes them. *then all minutes in specified range;* I see "excluding the time between 16:30:00 and 08:00:00" which means that `08:00:00` is a time of the next day - i.e. the timerange which must be included is `08:00:00..16:30:00` within one day. This range is geterated in CTE, and only overlapped timerange is accounted.

Comment: @Top-Master My fiddle contains one more query which shows partial timeranges which' lengths will be summarized. If this does not match to OP needs then I'd like to see the explanations from OP what is wrong and why... I'm used to people not always asking for what they want to ask for.

Comment: Oops, thought `08:00:00..16:30:00` needs to be excluded, will then update my own post ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Here is an object oriented approach. I'm on PHP version 7.4.9.

I'll assume you have the power that [Composer](https://getcomposer.org/) brings to PHP projects.

I've created this example using the [Carbon](https://github.com/briannesbitt/Carbon) library to immensly extend the default DateTime API.

```
use Carbon\Carbon;
use Carbon\CarbonPeriod;
use Carbon\CarbonInterval;

$start = Carbon::now();
$end = $start->copy()->addMonth();

$days = new CarbonPeriod($start, $end);
$workDays = [];

foreach ($days as $day) {
    if (! $day->isWeekend()) {
        $dayStart = $day->isSameDay($start) ?
            $start : $day->copy()->setTime(8, 00);
    
        $dayEnd = $day->isSameDay($end) ?
            $end : $day->copy()->setTime(16, 30);

        $workDays[] = new CarbonPeriod(
            $dayStart,
            $dayEnd,
            CarbonInterval::minute()
        );
    }
}
$minutes = 0;

foreach ($workDays as $workDay) {
   $minutes += iterator_count($workDay);
}
var_dump($minutes) // int(11242)
```

*Note that I haven't double checked the result.*

#### Test case

In order to **quickly** test this method you could use an [interactive PHP shell like PsySH](https://github.com/bobthecow/psysh).

In this case, I'll assume that:

- You're on a UNIX-like system.
- PHP is installed and available in your CLI.
- GIT is installed and available in your CLI.
- Composer is not installed/available.

```
git clone git@github.com:briannesbitt/Carbon.git carbon
cd carbon
php -r "copy('https://getcomposer.org/download/1.10.13/composer.phar', 'composer');"
chmod u+x composer
./composer install
./composer require psy/psysh
./vendor/bin/psysh
```

PsySH is running and you're in. Now copy the PHP code sample to your clipboard and paste in the PsySH shell.

Comment: let me get a quick tutorial on composer

Comment: No I had a trouble comprehending composer, is there no other way of achieving that without using composer?

Comment: There is no other option. Composer uses [PSR-4: Autoloader](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4) which is the standard in PHP to include files. Can you be more specific? Which kind of trouble are you running into?

Comment: I'm a newbie to programming, so I'm going to need some more time to understand composer. Right now I haven't been able to set it up.